# Counting how often occurs in a certain status column of the same table

Tags: php, mysql, count, records

I have one table like this:

```
id model status
1  Star  1
2  Star  0
3  Bana  0
4  Ship  1
5  Star  1
6  Ship  1
7  Ship  0
8  Bana  1
9  Bana  1
10 Ship  0
11 Ship  0
```

I want this:

```
Model On Off
Ship  2  3 
Star  2  1
Bana  2  1
```

I tried this but too long, when I have 8000 records on table....

```
SELECT a.model,
  (SELECT count(b.status) lib
   FROM SpaceShips b
   WHERE a.model=b.model
     AND b.status='1'
   GROUP BY b.model) ON,
  (SELECT count(c.status) blo
   FROM SpaceShips c
   WHERE a.model=c.model
     AND c.status='0'
   GROUP BY c.model) OFF
FROM SpaceShips a
WHERE (a.status='0'
       OR a.status='1')
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY model
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with:

```
SELECT
  model,
  SUM(status='0') AS Off,
  SUM(status='1') AS On
FROM
  SpaceShips
GROUP BY
  model
```

-I can't see any order in your sample desired output, so I've skipped it

Comment: nice, 63s to 0,0221 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    model,
    sum(if(status=1,1,0)) as on,
    sum(if(status=0,1,0)) as off
FROM
    SpaceShips
GROUP BY
    model
ORDER BY
    model
```

Comment: a litle slow, 0,0230s but not bad too. =)